# Web part always added at the bottom of a page

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, csom

I am adding a web part using the following code and xml:

```
string xemelek = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding=\"utf-8\"?><webParts><webPart xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3'><metaData><type name='Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' /><importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage></metaData><data><properties><property name='ListUrl' type='string' /><property name='ListId' type='System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'>757981FB-184A-441B-952D-9434BE33DC85</property><property name='ListName' type='string'>{757981FB-184A-441B-952D-9434BE33DC85}</property></properties></data></webPart></webParts>";
        
WebPartDefinition newWebiie = wpm.ImportWebPart(xemelek2);
WebPartDefinition webpartie = wpm.AddWebPart(newWebiie.WebPart, "ms-comm-homeWelcome ms-core-defaultFont", 0);
ctx.Load(newWebiie);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Whatever zoneId I use, the webpart always lands at the bottom of the page:
[image]

Inspect element shows the following zones:
[image]

What I tried so far:

- "Rich Content" - adds but at the bottom
- "ms-rte-layoutszone-outer" - adds but at the bottom
- "ms-rte-layoutszone-inner-editable ms-rtestate-write" - adds but at the bottom
- "mainContent" - adds at the bottom
- "wpz" - copied from a post on Wiki Page, did not work,
  no surprise
- "Zone 2", Index 0 and 3 - adds at the bottom
- "Top", Index 0 and 10 - adds at the bottom

I have set [ZoneIndex](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-Web-Parts-de33cc3b-b459-43cc-9f34-116f81755578) to 0 and this is the only web part in this zone, but this seems to have no effect.

How can I set the web part to be just under the page title like this?:
[image]

Settings from a manually added web part:
[image]

The same behaviour can be observed on multiple pages and several sites (all that I tested).

Comment: AddWebPart(newWebiie.WebPart, "ms-comm-homeWelcome ms-core-defaultFont", 0);, 2nd paramter in addwebpart is defined the zone of it... You can put Bottom or Main instead of the ms-comm...

Comment: Thanks Waqas, but I tried multiple options for the 2nd parameter, including Main and there is COMPLETELY no change whatsoever in the location of the webpart. To be clear, I do not move the web part, I re-add with every attempt.

Comment: One more observation - I suspect that the web parts are always added to the zone called "Bottom" regardless of the second parameter. Any ideas why the parameter could be ignored?